# Implications of optional<T> entering the C++ standard

Tags: c++, std, c++17

The [`std::optional<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional) construct has recently (?) been adopted into the C++17 language standard. Now, there are quite a few places in existing APIs in which `std::optional<T>` is a candidate to replace the return type of functions; essentially, these are functions which are an attempt to retrieve/produce something, which is not guaranteed to succeed:

- Finding an element in a container.
- Accessing a value in a map by its key.
- Allocating memory
- Establishing an input/output stream from a file or over the network

So, my question is: Is the standard committee considering (or even has it accepted) changes/additions to established APIs that involve the use of `std::optional`? If it is what parts of the standard (to your knowledge) are likely to change? And are such changes expected for C++17 or later?

Comment: I'd say existing interfaces are unlikely to change in a backward-incompatible way, and the return type change is definitely a breaking change.

Comment: @T.C.: Right you are. I'll edit that out.

Comment: This isn't a very good question for StackOverflow. The list of WG21 papers is public and permanently expanding. Any answer here would become stale rather soon.

Comment: `optional` does have a drawback w.r.t the size. So, should be used with efficiency in mind. See this https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2015/07/15/efficient-optional-values/. I am not sure though on whether any of the mentioned optimizations would be implemented by any compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the standard committee considering (or even has it accepted) changes/additions to established APIs that involve the use of `std::optional`?

Is it unlikely that the committee will change any of the current standard library use of things like `std::pair` until it is removed. If they had been "keen" on this, they would have applied something similar to changing use of `std::tuple` over `std::pair`.

Changes like this break APIs and the committee is "known" to be adverse to this unless (breaking backwards compatibility) they are relatively sure the breakages are minimal and the advantages of the change are greater than the breakages that would occur. I think `auto` is a reasonable example of this approach.

> If it is what parts of the standard (to your knowledge) are likely to change? And are such changes expected for C++17 or later?

Expect new additions to the library to use the newer additions to the library. So, basically, expect new classes to use `std::optional` (as required).